# Sum of weights in portfolio theory is not equal to 1?

Tags: modeling, optimization, finance, weights

I'm trying to understand basic portfolio theory using R. As far as I understood, the sum of the weights of assets must be equal to 1 .
But in this link, that teaches how to compute the efficient frontier of a portfolio, the final sum of the weights is not equal to 1. What this means?

Link of tutorial:
http://economistatlarge.com/portfolio-theory/r-optimized-portfolio

Weights final result:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have misunderstood (I think it's pretty clearly explained at your link).

Each *row* gives a set of weights, across the first six columns. Those do indeed sum to 1. Note that some weights are negative.

The collection of rows defines the frontier.

Comment: Ok, but in a practical example, how should I invest the 100% of my money? If some weights are negative, what this means?

Comment: That's not a stats question, but a finance question. Why not ask the person whose blog you linked?

Comment: Or migrate to quant.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Negative weights correspond to short-selling the asset.  You borrow these and immediately sell them, adding to the cash used to buy the assets with positive weights. Any realistic theory will incorporate the (sometimes heavy) ongoing costs of paying interest on the borrowed assets, but these are often neglected for illustrative purposes.

Comment: @whuber +1 I really wasn't sure of the extent to which it would be reasonable to discuss short selling here and figured it would be better to send the OP for more expert advice - but I guess a couple of sentences is fair enough.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help! sorry, I though the interpretation of data/math was also a theme of the forum